# Update a field in mysql table on click

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a binary field in a mysql database that gets updated by a button on an html form.

So, I click the button for every row and it changes the mysql value for each of the rows…

The problem is that it has a delay, when I click on one button of a certain row it only gets updated when I click on the next. But if I click on that button and refresh the page it gets changed.

I've look into ways of updating the page, but I just can't get it to work...

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
<input type=hidden name='keyword2' value='$keyword'>
<input type='submit' value = 'SELECT' >
</form>";

<?php 

j($_POST['keyword2']);
function j($q){
    $n = "SELECT `CÔR` FROM `keywords` WHERE `keyword`='$q'";
    $b = mysql_query ($n);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($b);
    echo $row['CÔR'];
    $t = $row['CÔR'];

    if ($t == 1) {
        $m = "UPDATE `keywords` SET `CÔR`=0 WHERE `keyword`='$q'";
        mysql_query ($m);
    }

    if ($t == 0) {
        $l = "UPDATE `keywords` SET `CÔR`=1 WHERE `keyword`='$q'";
        mysql_query ($l);
    }
```

Comment: if you want to do without reloading page do this by ajax

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: i really dont appreciate one word function name ... i mean function name should be according functionality

Comment: No, I have no problem in reloading the page... The problem and it maybe because I'm messing things up, is that with the code I got in the internet it keeps reloading and doesn't stop... can You tell me why? I've tried about 10 different scripts!

Comment: One of them is the following:   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php"> it doesn't stop refreshing...

Comment: so you gave the answer to yourself.. :-)